# Pynmea2 attribute error

Tags: python-2.7

I've been using the pynmea2 library, but today I ran a GPGGA message through it and it's throwing an attribute error when trying to access the objects datetime method.

```
>>> from pynmea2 import parse
>>> a = '$GPGGA,201326.000,3348.5072,N,11809.6409,W,2,20,0.55,37.5,M,-34.3,M,0000,0000*65'
>>> msg = parse(a)
>>> msg
<GGA(timestamp=datetime.time(20, 13, 26), lat='3348.5072', lat_dir='N', lon='11809.6409', lon_dir='W', gps_qual='2', num_sats='20', horizontal_dil='0.55', altitude=37.5, altitude_units='M', geo_sep='-34.3', geo_sep_units='M', age_gps_data='0000', ref_station_id='0000')>
>>> msg.datetime
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pynmea2/nmea.py", line 154, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: datetime
```

Here's what line 154 and everything related states in nmea.py:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    #pylint: disable=invalid-name
    t = type(self)
    try:
        i = t.name_to_idx[name]
    except KeyError:
        raise AttributeError(name)
    f = t.fields[i]
    if i < len(self.data):
        v = self.data[i]
    else:
        v = ''
    if len(f) >= 3:
        if v == '':
            return None
        return f[2](v)
    else:
        return v
```

Any ideas what this could be?
Thanks for looking at this!

Comment: Found it...GPGGA sentences have no date values in their string.

Answer (score 0):

Found it...GPGGA sentences have no date values in their string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to access the timestamp attribute of the GPGGA record, using:

```
>>> from pynmea2 import parse
>>> a = '$GPGGA,201326.000,3348.5072,N,11809.6409,W,2,20,0.55,37.5,M,-34.3,M,0000,0000*65'
>>> msg = parse(a)
>>> msg
<GGA(timestamp=datetime.time(20, 13, 26), lat='3348.5072', lat_dir='N', lon='11809.6409', lon_dir='W', gps_qual='2', num_sats='20', horizontal_dil='0.55', altitude=37.5, altitude_units='M', geo_sep='-34.3', geo_sep_units='M', age_gps_data='0000', ref_station_id='0000')>
>>> msg.timestamp
datetime.time(20, 13, 26)
```